# How to accepts files in post request of lambda and also validate the form type data using Pydantics

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, pydantic

I am writing an API which accept files, upload it in s3 & dump the url in DynamoDB's table. As the payload would contain the files so it needs to be a ***multipart form data***.

When I generally accept JSON as payload I use ***Pydantics*** to validate payload schema, attribute's datatype and its values. I am not aware of how to validate the ***multipart form data*** in using Pydantic. Is it possible to validate ***multipart form data using*** ***Pydantics***? If yes any short example would be helpful.